# Automating the deployment of a CLR database project to the database

Tags: .net, database, deployment, clr

We have a CLR database project in VS08. Right now, everytime we do a build there are multiple manual steps that have to be performed in order to deploy this project as part of our build process.
I ended up writing a utility that automates parts of this process. I am wondering if there are are better tools - or even devenv switch that I am missing - to automatically deploy CLR objects to the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any automatic switch that does this, though it would be great if there was (maybe in VS2010? Listening, Microsoft?). If I had to do this, I'd either write a custom utility and reference it as a post-build step, or I'd write a script that uses OSQL to execute the SQL needed to import the DLL and mark it.

I'd be interested to know if there's a more integrated way, but I wouldn't get your hopes up, and since the method you have seems to be working, I'd stick with it.